# Strict aliasing rule in C++11

Tags: c++11, postgis, strict-aliasing

I use the following C structs in my C++11 code (the code comes from liblwgeom of PostGis, but this is not the core of the question). The code is compiled with the following options using g++-4.8:

```
-std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -pedantic -Werror
```

and I don't get any errors during compilation (or warnings) (should I get any?)

### Question

Is safe to use `LWPOLY` (actually pointed by `LWGEOM*`) in functions that accept `LWGEOM` and don't modify the `void *data;` member. I understand that this is poor man's inheritance but this is what I need to work with.

### Details

POLYGON:

```
typedef struct
{
        uint8_t type; /* POLYGONTYPE */
        uint8_t flags;
        GBOX *bbox;
        int32_t srid;
        int nrings;   /* how many rings we are currently storing */
        int maxrings; /* how many rings we have space for in **rings */
        POINTARRAY **rings; /* list of rings (list of points) */
}
LWPOLY; /* "light-weight polygon" */
```

LWGEOM:

```
typedef struct
{
        uint8_t type;
        uint8_t flags;
        GBOX *bbox;
        int32_t srid;
        void *data;
}
LWGEOM;
```

POINTARRAY:

```
typedef struct
{
        /* Array of POINT 2D, 3D or 4D, possibly missaligned. */
        uint8_t *serialized_pointlist;

        /* Use FLAGS_* macros to handle */
        uint8_t  flags;

        int npoints;   /* how many points we are currently storing */
        int maxpoints; /* how many points we have space for in serialized_pointlist */
}
POINTARRAY;
```

GBOX:

```
typedef struct
{
        uint8_t flags;
        double xmin;
        double xmax;
        double ymin;
        double ymax;
        double zmin;
        double zmax;
        double mmin;
        double mmax;
} GBOX;
```

Am I violating strict aliasing rule when I do something like?

```
const LWGEOM* lwgeom;
...
const LWPOLY* lwpoly = reinterpret_cast<const LWPOLY*>(lwgeom);
```

I know that in PostGis types are specifically designed to be "compatible" however I'd like to know if I am violating the standard by doing so.

Also, I noticed that PostGis is not compiled with strict aliasing disabled by default (at least version 2.1.5).

## Solution

My colleague helped me to investigate it and it seems the answer is No it doesn't violate strict aliasing, but only in case we access LWGEOMS members that are of the same type as of LWPOLY's and are laid out in the beginning of the struct contiguously. Here is why (quoting standard):

`3.10.10` says that you can access a member through a pointer to "aggregate or union".

`8.5.1` defines aggregates (C structs are aggregates):
An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 9) with no user-provided constructors (12.1), no private or
protected non-static data members (Clause 11), no base classes (Clause 10), and no virtual functions (10.3).

`9.2.19` says that pointer to the struct is the same as pointer to the fist member for standard layout classes (C structs are standard layout).

Whether this is a safe way to code is a different question.

Comment: Yes that would most definitely break the string aliasing rule.

Comment: my very personal opinion is, that one should not cast between different structs but *parse* them.

Comment: This line is present in the standard: "an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its elements or non-
static data members (including, recursively, an element or non-static data member of a subaggregate
or contained union)" but I am not sure I can interpret it correctly

Comment: This is probably poor man's inheritance. (A polygon is a geometric shape.) Can you wrap them with your own classes, explicitly inherit LWPOLY from LWGEOM and do a dynamic or static cast? The library code will never be alias safe, but your own would.

Comment: @Alex this is a high performance library, parsing would be an overkill (my subjective opinion)

Comment: @Alex have you read the question?

Comment: @Alex thanks. I guess the question is poorly written. I have edited the question. Basically the intent was to ask whether it is safe to use LWPOLY (actually pointed by LWGEOM*) in functions that accept LWGEOM and don't modify the  `void *data;` member.

Comment: @Alex I've read ) thanks again

Comment: *"... in functions that accept LWGEOM"* Could you change these functions? Perhaps a function template that accept `LWGEOM` or `LWPOLY`? Or perhaps these are functions within the external library that you are not able to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it violates the strict aliasing rule. `LWGEOM` and `LWPOLY` are unrelated types, and so are `int` and `void*`. So, for example, modification to `lwgeom->data` may not be read through `lwpoly->nrings` and vice versa.

I validated this with GCC4.9. My code is as follows:

```
#include <cinttypes>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef struct {
        uint8_t type; /* POLYGONTYPE */
        uint8_t flags;
        int32_t srid;
        int nrings;   /* how many rings we are currently storing */
} LWPOLY; /* "light-weight polygon" */

typedef struct {
        uint8_t type;
        uint8_t flags;
        int32_t srid;
        void *data;
} LWGEOM;

void f(LWGEOM* pgeom, LWPOLY* ppoly) {
    ppoly->nrings = 7;
    pgeom->data = 0;
    std::cout << ppoly->nrings << '\n';
}

int main() {
    LWGEOM geom = {};
    LWGEOM* pgeom = &geom;
    LWPOLY* ppoly = (LWPOLY*)pgeom;
    f(pgeom, ppoly);
}
```

Guess what, the output is 7.

Comment: they have standard layout (see my edit of the question) and members are laid out in the same order (with members being of the same type) so according to the standard the setup doesn't violate strict aliasing rule

Comment: @iggy See the update of my answer. I've verified the violation on GCC4.9.

Comment: yes, you are right, I have underspecified the question. However there is no violation according to the standard if you access the common part (so the first 3 members)

Comment: same member type doesn't imply that there is no aliasing though. If one type is a POD struct and the other is a class with virtual member functions and otherwise both having the same members this wouldn't work

Comment: After some tests on GCC and clang. I found, somehow surprisingly, that the same problem exists even for the first 3 members.

Comment: are you compiling with `-std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -pedantic -Werror` ?

Comment: `g++ -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out` I guess `-O2` is what makes things different.